# Kiosk mode and auto login and single application mode in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, kde, kiosk, qt

We have a machine running **CentOS 7, GDM, KDE 11** (installed from CentOS DVD)

We have been struggling a few days with this issue, tried to search for a solution but unfortunately most of the material's were outdated, including KDE Kiosk Tool which gives a broken link, so we decided it's time to give up and ask for SE's wisdom.

We want to run a GUI Applcation (Not a browser like on most kiosk cases, but instead a Java Executable JAR - for the purpose of the question let's call it **"Shop"**) With the following features:

1. The machine should boot & log in automatically, enter KDE and autorun the application on Full-Screen Mode
2. The User can't run anything else but this application, and can't exit it (maybe by hiding the top menu with the minimize & close button)
3. The app needs to be able to write to the Hard Drive and that the files written will be kept after rebooting
4. A Splash screen on startup (This point I believe is less important, as we've seen it's configurable on KDE's settings)
5. KDE Menus should be hidden, i.e the user should only see that application

A few extra points:

- We can consider changing from KDE to GNOME if this helps making the solution easier.
- We can consider downloading another dist if this helps making the solution easier
- The application's GUI is based on **QT Libraries**, and **Java**

Answer (score 0):

Do not run KDE or Gnome. Use either .xsession or .xinitrc to run the application instead of a desktop. Combine this with auto-login.